# How to delete rows with specific pattern of numbers in between

Tags: bash

Imagine I have the following file name xx00. How can I remove lines after 4th line that are more than 60 between 3rd and 4th comma?

```
@0035e19a runid=6e9cba070 sampleid=190724  
CAGTATACTTCGTTCAGTTATGCTGGGCGGCGACCTCATG  
+  
&$'&&%',&')-,1:96,)$$$,'##&'%,&2&&,&:?,953,7=&&*&<6CC@@3486
(0,0): 255, 0, 40, 0, 255, 255,  
(1,0): 255, 0, 254, 1, 255, 255,  
(2,0): 254, 1, 255, 0, 255, 255,  
(3,0): 255, 0, 254, 1, 255, 255,  
(4,0): 255, 0, 50, 0, 255, 255,  
(5,0): 255, 0, 254, 1, 255, 255,  
(6,0): 255, 0, 253, 2, 255, 255,  
(7,0): 255, 0, 90, 0, 255, 255,  
(8,0): 255, 0, 33, 1, 255, 255,
```

The output should be like this.

```
@0035e19a runid=6e9cba070 sampleid=190724  
CAGTATACTTCGTTCAGTTATGCTGGGCGGCGACCTCATG  
+  
&$'&&%',&')-,1:96,)$$$,'##&'%,&2&&,&:?,953,7=&&*&<6CC@@3486  
(0,0): 255, 0, 40, 0, 255, 255,  
(4,0): 255, 0, 50, 0, 255, 255,   
(8,0): 255, 0, 33, 1, 255, 255,
```

I also need to keep the spaces at the first line but this code in 'tr' part removes all spaces.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F, 'NR<=4 || $4<=60' xx00
```

For example:

```
 $ awk -F, 'NR<=4 || $4<=60' xx00
@0035e19a runid=6e9cba070 sampleid=190724  
CAGTATACTTCGTTCAGTTATGCTGGGCGGCGACCTCATG  
+  
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)$$$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@34865693012@>AFEAA  
(0,0): 255, 0, 40, 0, 255, 255,  
(4,0): 255, 0, 50, 0, 255, 255,  
(8,0): 255, 0, 33, 1, 255, 255,
```

#### How it works

awk reads in files one line (record) at a time and each line is divided into fields.

- `-F,`
  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator.
- `NR<=4 || $4<=60`

  This tells awk to print the line if either (a) the line number is four or below, or (b) the value of the fourth field is less than or equal to 60.

Comment: Hi, **No it does not work**. Actually, there are a bunch of commas in my 4th line, too. But because it was so long I just paste the first part of it.

Comment: Also, I need to remove lines more than 60 but it keeps them

Comment: Commas in the fourth line should have no effect.  Please [edit] your question and add some sample data for which this answer "does not work."

Comment: @Vahid As I read it, your desired output shows only the lines greater than 60.  Is that sample output not what you want?

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry. @John1024 you are right I will edit it right now.

Comment: Thank you so much @John1024: Based on your code I wrote this and worked:    cat xx00 | awk -F, 'NR<=4 || $4<60' | more